# Unknown media type error while installing

Tags: fedora, software-installation, python, editors

I'm trying to *install* [gmate](https://github.com/gmate/gmate) on *fedora 23*

First, it require *some packages*: `pywebkitgtk`, `python-sexy`, `python-inotify` and `ack`

> Installing them without *any problems*:

```
[root@host gmate] # dnf install pywebkitgtk python-sexy python-inotify ack
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:21:24 ago on Mon Mar  7 23:14:49 2016.
Dependencies resolved.
==================================================================================================
 Package                   Arch              Version                      Repository         Size
==================================================================================================
Installing:
 ack                       noarch            2.14-3.fc23                  fedora             77 k
 libsexy                   x86_64            0.1.11-25.fc23               fedora             50 k
 perl-File-Next            noarch            1.12-7.fc23                  fedora             24 k
 python-inotify            noarch            0.9.6-2.fc23                 fedora             55 k
 python-sexy               x86_64            0.1.9-21.fc23                fedora             31 k
 pywebkitgtk               x86_64            1.1.8-10.fc23                fedora             66 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================
Install  6 Packages

Total download size: 302 k
Installed size: 871 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/6): python-sexy-0.1.9-21.fc23.x86_64.rpm                       9.9 kB/s |  31 kB     00:03    
(2/6): pywebkitgtk-1.1.8-10.fc23.x86_64.rpm                        20 kB/s |  66 kB     00:03    
(3/6): python-inotify-0.9.6-2.fc23.noarch.rpm                      16 kB/s |  55 kB     00:03    
(4/6): perl-File-Next-1.12-7.fc23.noarch.rpm                       35 kB/s |  24 kB     00:00    
(5/6): libsexy-0.1.11-25.fc23.x86_64.rpm                           43 kB/s |  50 kB     00:01    
(6/6): ack-2.14-3.fc23.noarch.rpm                                  51 kB/s |  77 kB     00:01    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                              38 kB/s | 302 kB     00:08     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Installing  : perl-File-Next-1.12-7.fc23.noarch                                             1/6 
  Installing  : libsexy-0.1.11-25.fc23.x86_64                                                 2/6 
  Installing  : python-sexy-0.1.9-21.fc23.x86_64                                              3/6 
  Installing  : ack-2.14-3.fc23.noarch                                                        4/6 
  Installing  : python-inotify-0.9.6-2.fc23.noarch                                            5/6 
  Installing  : pywebkitgtk-1.1.8-10.fc23.x86_64                                              6/6 
  Verifying   : pywebkitgtk-1.1.8-10.fc23.x86_64                                              1/6 
  Verifying   : python-sexy-0.1.9-21.fc23.x86_64                                              2/6 
  Verifying   : python-inotify-0.9.6-2.fc23.noarch                                            3/6 
  Verifying   : ack-2.14-3.fc23.noarch                                                        4/6 
  Verifying   : libsexy-0.1.11-25.fc23.x86_64                                                 5/6 
  Verifying   : perl-File-Next-1.12-7.fc23.noarch                                             6/6 

Installed:
  ack.noarch 2.14-3.fc23                          libsexy.x86_64 0.1.11-25.fc23                   
  perl-File-Next.noarch 1.12-7.fc23               python-inotify.noarch 0.9.6-2.fc23              
  python-sexy.x86_64 0.1.9-21.fc23                pywebkitgtk.x86_64 1.1.8-10.fc23                

Complete!
[root@host gmate] #
```

> Trying to install *gmate*

```
[root@host gmate] # git clone git://github.com/gmate/gmate.git
Cloning into 'gmate'...
remote: Counting objects: 3692, done.
remote: Total 3692 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3692
Receiving objects: 100% (3692/3692), 1.58 MiB | 82.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1914/1914), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[root@host gmate] # cd gmate
[root@host gmate] # ls
create-release.sh  gmate.py    keybindings.txt  mime     README.md  styles
debian             install.sh  lang-specs       plugins  snippets   tags
[root@host gmate] # sh install.sh
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-alchemy'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cache'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cactvs-ascii'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cactvs-binary'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cactvs-table'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cdx'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cdxml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-chem3d'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cif'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-daylight-smiles'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-dmol'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gamess-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gamess-output'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gaussian-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gaussian-log'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-genbank'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gulp'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-hin'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-inchi'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-inchi-xml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-jcamp-dx'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-macromodel-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-molfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-rdfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-rxnfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-sdfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-tgf'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mmcif'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mol2'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mopac-graph'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mopac-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mopac-out'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-car'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-hessian'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-mdf'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-msi'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-ncbi-asn1'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-ncbi-asn1-binary'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-ncbi-asn1-xml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-pdb'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-shelx'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-turbomole-basis'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-turbomole-control'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-turbomole-coord'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-turbomole-grad'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-turbomole-scfmo'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-turbomole-vibrational'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-vmd'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-xyz'
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
[root@host gmate] #
```

Anybody has any idea, i'm trying to solve this for hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a known bug:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1336932

But it still has not been resolved (as of Fedora 27).

Answer (score 0):

Might be the problem in your server's mime database.

You need to check /usr/share/mime/packages for the specific xml that contains the phrase you get.

**Try this:**

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Comment: it does not work.. shows the same message of `Unknown media type in type`